# Are replacement kitchen sprayers fairly interchangeable?

Tags: faucet, plumbing-fixture

Well, first house break-down of the year happened about 6 hours into 2013...  The wife grabbed the kitchen sink sprayer and snapped the lever off of it.  No leak, but it doesn't work anymore.  Am I going to be able to find a compatible replacement sprayer in the local store, or do I have to go back to the manufacturer?  Wondering if these are all a standard design (like toilet guts seem to be)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the most part hardware stores will carry universal side sprayers, that can be used to replace broken sprayers from nearly all manufacturers.  You might come across a proprietary side sprayer from time to time, but chances are a universal replacement will work.  You may not find a sprayer that matches the look and design of the broken sprayer exactly, but a replacement should attach and function without problems.

Keep in mind, this only applies to side sprays.

[image]

If you break the pull down sprayer, you'll likely have to get a replacement from the manufacturer.

[image]

Comment: Excellent.  It's a side sprayer, I'll hit up the hardware shops in the hopes of finding a usable match!

Comment: Update.  Never had to.  I figured out how to fix the one I have!  It *looked* like it snapped off, but that's just apparently due to the mold.  Was able to line everything back up again with the handle, apply significant pressure and get it back together again.  not sure how she managed to bust it, it's solid now, just like it was before!